# Sprites displaying in front of FadeIn panel in Unity

Tags: sprite, layer

I have sprites attached to a Panel. They are all on the Foreground Layer. I also have a Panel for FadeIn and FadeOut. That Panel is on its own FadeLayer which is in front of everything. The problem is that the sprites always show in front of the Fade Panel. I have changed layers on everything but nothing seems to work. The text that is on the same panel as the sprites don't show, only the sprites. Any ideas? Thanks